# I'm receiving unknown/empty response from MS Graph (JS SDK) when trying to copy file

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to copy file from one location to another in sharepoint site, I'm receiving ReadableStream instead of URL to Location as in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript). When trying to read that stream as Response, it seems to be empty anyways. Here is part of my code where I'm trying to do it:

```
    try {
      client
        .api(`/sites/${siteId}/drive/items/${fileTag}/copy`)
        .version('beta')
        .post({
          parentReference: {
            driveId: folderData.driveId,
            id: folderData.id,
          },
          '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior': 'replace',
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          console.log(stream);
          return new Response(stream);
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        'There was an error whem trying to copy file.',
        HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
      );
    }
```

What's important - file copying is working, at least for the first time. When I'm trying to copy again with rewrite policy, nothing is happening. I need to be able to copy file multiple times and overwrite it (so changes are visible in history).

Here is the response:

```
ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: { settingsObject: {} },
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: false,
    requestIncludesCredentials: false,
    type: 'default',
    status: 200,
    timingInfo: null,
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: '',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(0) {},
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [],
    body: { stream: undefined, source: null, length: null }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(0) {},
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

I was checking if removing beta would work (as it's set [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/long-running-actions-overview?tabs=http)), but no difference. I haven't found any other information about this error appearing in this endpoint.

Was checking type of stream (using .text(), .formData(), etc) but in all of them it seems to be empty.